# RESTEasy return PDF if succeed and and return XML if fail

Tags: java, xml, pdf, resteasy

I'm trying to make a RESTful web service using RESTEasy. This is my Resource interface:

```
@Path("/report/{bookId}") 
@GET 
@Produces({"application/pdf", "application/xml"}) 
public Response getReport(@PathParam("bookId")Long book);
```

And in the Service implementation bean:

```
responseBuilder = Response.status(200).entity(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()).type("application/pdf");
            responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Report.pdf\"");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseBuilder = Response.status(500).entity(new ErrorDTO("123",
                    "Could not get the report. Cause by " + e.getMessage()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseBuilder.build();
```

But it does not work this way. If the return entity is the PDF, it always attempt to parse the entity to XML.

I want to return PDF if succeed and and return XML if fail. 
Any idea?
Thank in advanced!

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access this resource. I can't reproduce the behavior you are experiencing

Comment: Hi peeskillet, I use both firefox and rest client addon to access the resource